# What's the difference between these authorization APIs?

Tags: github, oauth, authorization, github-api

What is the difference between

```
POST /authorizations
```

and

```
PUT /authorizations/clients/:client_id
```

in the GitHub API? Both receive a `client_id` (the latter in the URL, the former in the POST parameters). What is the difference?

Comment: Is the only difference that the first always creates a new authorization and the later creates a new authorization only when there was no authorization for this client and scopes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: the former will always create a new token (potentially matching an existing one), whereas the latter will either return an existing token matching the POST data, or create and return one should it not already exist.